# How I mange balance sheet in netsuite? after removing some test transaction record. Is any effect on journal ledger?

Tags: netsuite

after removing some test transaction record or disabling customer records  Is any effect on journal ledger.

Answer (score 0):

I guess making a Customer inactive in Netsuite doesn't impact anything on the accounting side though deleting any of your transaction may impact your Balance Sheet and Chart of Account. If you're on production, I would recommend not to delete any transaction data rather try to do some journal posting to make your transaction effect void.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I have one more doubt like when I have deleted all the entries for test customer like(Opportunity,salesorder, journal). than also I have impact on journal ledger. It means journal ledger will not be in balance.